# File length retrieval from unclosed FileOutputStream

Tags: java, validation, fileoutputstream, try-with-resources

A custom file format being devised requires robust file corruption checking, currently implemented via a SHA-2 checksum appended at the end of the file. Given the large sizes of the given file, it takes a while to validate the SHA-2 checksums and thus it has been decided to place the final file size near the start of the file to quickly filter out files with mismatched file lengths.

Maybe I am just thinking too much, but is there anyway the following example will fail?

```
File outputFile = ... // Output file

try(FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
    FileChannel fChannel = fOut.getChannel()){

    fOut.write(MAGIC);       // byte array to magic header
    fOut.write(new Byte[8]); // reserve space for eventual file size

    //// [Bulk Writing to File] ////

    // Ensure all writing is complete

    fOut.flush();

    fOut.getFD().sync(); // Is this necessary?

    // Write final file size to file

    ByteBuffer finalFileSize = ByteBuffer.allocate(8);
    finalFileSize.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
    finalFileSize.putLong(outputFile.length()); // Will this statement return an inaccurate file length?

    fChannel.position(MAGIC.length);
    fChannel.write(finalFileSize);

}catch(IOException ex){
    // Exception handle code... deletes current file and starts again.
}
```

I am particularly worried about `outputFile.length()` returning an invalid length due to the file stream being unclosed (and thus some bytes could persist in memory/metadata not updated on specific platforms).

In my particular case, having the filelength simply be unavailable (written as 0) is better than having it be invalid since the corruption detection code will ignore file lengths <= 0 and move on SHA-2 validation but will reject positive filelength mismatches.

Is my implementation sufficient or do I need to resort to writing a counting stream wrapper around the FIS to make sure the file length is correct?

Comment: Don't really know the answer, but for what it's worth, it looks good to me. If you end up needing to count bytes that passed through the stream, both Apache commons IO and Guava libs have such a stream already implemented.

Comment: @kaqqao I'm aware of Apache's counting streams, seems excessive to list the whole of commons-io as a dependency for such a trivial task. I appreciate the input though...

Comment: Well you certainly need to count the output ourself. You don't need to write a filtered stream to do that, you can just add up the bytes being transferred as you go.

Comment: @EJP Its not as simple as that in my case since I have many filter streams being applied successfully that don't make clear how many bytes are written to the underlying stream (think things like ZipOutputStream).

Comment: If a ZipOutputStream is involved, then flushing() will not (always) do it : ZIP performs operations on close() that are not always done on a simple flush(), see DeflaterOutputStream.finish() and the use of syncModes. I'd consider this code risky at best, as it makes too many assumptions about implementation stuff like that. (I'd rather close the file, reopen it in random access mode, and write the size. If the file is Zipped, then it might be large enough so that the extra syscalls are cheap, for the safety they buy, your mileage may vary)